# Pi camera works, no feed

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, imutils

This friday my camera worked, when I turned it on today it wasn't receiving any feed.
My camera does work (the robot I am creating shows response based on camera feedback) and the light turns on. I have stripped the code to bare-bone and even then it doesn't work.

```
import math
from cv2 import findContours
from distance.HCSRO4Component import *
from drive.dcMotorIndu import *
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from threading import *
import os
import time
import logging

try:
    from imutils.video.pivideostream import PiVideoStream
    import imutils
except ImportError:
    logging.warning("Couldn't import PiCamera, continuing wihout...")
    

camIsPi = True
# Check whether cam arg is Pi camera

rotation = 90
vs = PiVideoStream(rotation=rotation).start()
time.sleep(1)

cycleOn = True
while (cycleOn == True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    frame = vs.read()
    print(frame)
    #frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)                
    cv.imshow("Video capture (Final result)", frame)
```

The print statement returns data, but when I pass it to `imshow` it opens the camera, but no feed is shown. I have tried putting the `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2` in the kernel. I have also turned on and off the `enable camera` on my pi and have tried every other solution basically.
When calling `vcgencmd get_camera` it returns `supported=1 detected=1`.

What could possibly cause this error now? I need the camera feed to show on my pi. Stripping it to such barebone code and still not having any feed tells me it most likely isn't my code which is causing the error(?)

Comment: Does this help? ret,  frame = vs.read() if not ret: break

Comment: Too many values to unpakc @toyotaSupra

Comment: Ok remove it. But I can only work around w/out using imutils.

Comment: @toyotaSupra As long as it works with pi, you're free to make whatever workaround.

Comment: You had waitKey() on it?  I can do 2 thing using picamera (1) Videocapture api and (2)  Picameras api.

Comment: @toyotaSupra I do have one in my main-code, but not in this one. Basically I am just trying to get the feed back.

Comment: perhaps try the https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/